# A site is upgraded but not to the latest version because Drush isn't upgraded to the lastest version - why does it happen and how to upgrade Drush?

Tags: 10, upgrading

A site was upgraded from 10.1.7 to 10.1.8 instead to 10.2.2.

There were no errors along the upgrade process but from `composer why-not drupal/core 10.2.2` it is indicated that my Drush version is too old.

```
drupal/core-recommended    10.1.8 requires         drupal/core (10.1.8)
drupal/core                10.2.2 conflicts        drush/drush (<12.4.3)
drupal/core                10.2.2 requires         symfony/console (^6.4)
drupal/recommended-project -      does not require symfony/console (but v6.3.12 is installed)
drupal/core                10.2.2 requires         symfony/dependency-injection (^6.4)
drupal/recommended-project -      does not require symfony/dependency-injection (but v6.3.12 is installed)
drupal/core                10.2.2 requires         symfony/event-dispatcher (^6.4)
drupal/recommended-project -      does not require symfony/event-dispatcher (but v6.3.12 is installed)
drupal/core                10.2.2 requires         symfony/http-foundation (^6.4)
drupal/recommended-project -      does not require symfony/http-foundation (but v6.3.12 is installed)
drupal/core                10.2.2 requires         symfony/http-kernel (^6.4)
drupal/recommended-project -      does not require symfony/http-kernel (but v6.3.12 is installed)
drupal/core                10.2.2 requires         symfony/mime (^6.4)
drupal/recommended-project -      does not require symfony/mime (but v6.3.12 is installed)
drupal/core                10.2.2 requires         symfony/routing (^6.4)
drupal/recommended-project -      does not require symfony/routing (but v6.3.12 is installed)
drupal/core                10.2.2 requires         symfony/serializer (^6.4)
drupal/recommended-project -      does not require symfony/serializer (but v6.3.12 is installed)
drupal/core                10.2.2 requires         symfony/validator (^6.4)
drupal/recommended-project -      does not require symfony/validator (but v6.3.12 is installed)
drupal/core                10.2.2 requires         symfony/process (^6.4)
drupal/recommended-project -      does not require symfony/process (but v6.3.12 is installed)
drupal/core                10.2.2 requires         symfony/yaml (^6.4)
drupal/recommended-project -      does not require symfony/yaml (but v6.3.12 is installed)
Not finding what you were looking for? Try calling `composer update "drupal/core:10.2.2" --dry-run` to get another view on the problem.
```

I was inclined in the comments to remove Drush, upgrade Drupal project, re-add Drush, and only then to try to update Drupal DB with Drush, but a shorter approach then removing and re-adding Drush would be to just update Drush.
I have always assumed that `composer update` on a Drupal project will also upgrade Drush due to the global nature of this command and because Drush is an add-on to the a Drupal project, but Drush isn't upgraded this way, so I ask here how to upgrade Drush?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message

```
drupal/core                10.2.2 conflicts        drush/drush (<12.4.3)
```

Drupal core 10.2.2 has defined a conflict with Drush <12.4.3. If you are still using Drush 11 update it first:

```
composer require 'drush/drush:^12.4' --no-update
composer update
```

The option `--no-update` in the first line only updates the composer.json file - the same as if you would have edited composer.json in a text editor - before the general composer update runs all updates in one step.

The reason Drush is not updated automatically is semantic versioning. A MAJOR version update can have API changes and therefore manual intervention is required. See https://semver.org/

If the update is still not working check the PHP version in the command line (php -v) and update composer itself:

```
composer self-update
```